# Auto completion duplicates text [Kile]

Tags: kile, auto-completion

When I try to autocomplete an argument in Kile it ends up writing the entire command and ignores what I wrote, like this:

> \document

> \document\documentclass{}

I'm not sure what's causing this, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: which Kile version are you using?